# How to write a SQL statement to return all children of each root,extend to each root

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table.
the value of [contents] can insert any word(Below are just examples)

```
create table #TreeTable (
     Id uniqueidentifier,       
     Contents NVARCHAR(200),
     ParentId uniqueidentifier,
     Floors Int,
     Sort Int,
)

  insert into #TreeTable([Id], [ParentId], [Contents],[Floors],[Sort]) values
    (1, 0, '1',1,1),
    (2, 0, '2',1,2),
    (3, 1, '1-1',2,1),
    (4, 1, '1-2',2,2),
    (5, 2, '2-1',2,1),
    (6, 3, '1-1-1',3,1),
    (7, 4, '1-2-1',3,1);
    (8, 4, '1-2-2',3,2),
    (9, 6, '1-1-1-1',4,1),
    (10, 6,'1-1-1-2',4,2);
```

I want to write a T-SQL statement that will return all children of each root with the root ID　and Below is the result I expected

```
[Id][ParentId][Contents] [Levels][Sort]
(1,   0,       '1',       1,      1)
(3,   1,       '1-1',     2,      1)
(6,   3,       '1-1-1',   3,      1)
(9,   6,       '1-1-1-1', 4,      1)
(10,  6,       '1-1-1-2', 4,      2)
(4,   1,       '1-2',     2,      2)
(7,   4,       '1-2-1',   3,      1)
(8,   4,       '1-2-2',   3,      2)
(2,   0,       '2',       1,      2)
(5,   2,       '2-1',     2,      1)
```

The depth of the tree may be arbitrarily long

I try to use this ，but the reuslt is not what i expected

```
with RecursiveTable as(
        ------ start-------
      SELECT a.*
      FROM TreeTable a
     WHERE
      a.ParentId  = 0
       ------ end ---------
        union all
      SELECT b.*
      FROM TreeTable b
      join RecursiveTable a on a.Id =b.ParentId
        )
     select * from RecursiveTable
```

Comment: If you are writing a T-SQL statement that would be MS SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: i use the c# mvc to get data by microsoft sql sever，what is the tag to use?

Comment: you originally used the `MySQL` tag, that is not correct. You should have used the `sql-server` tag. I updated it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we may believe `[Contents]` values, then simply

```
SELECT [Id], 
       [ParentId],
       [Contents],
       LEN([Contents]) - LEN(REPLACE([Contents], '-', '')) + 1 [Levels],
       [Sort]
FROM #TreeTable
ORDER BY [Contents];
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=8ccb7ed66b5e91e2a278ad74f870e352)

If not then

```
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT [Id], [ParentId], CAST([Sort] AS NCHAR), [Sort], 1 [Levels]
FROM #TreeTable
WHERE [ParentId] = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT t.[Id], t.[ParentId], cte.[Contents] + '-' + t.[Sort], t.[Sort], 1 + cte.[Levels]
FROM #TreeTable t
JOIN cte ON t.[ParentId] = cte.[Id]
)
SELECT [Id], [ParentId], [Contents], [Levels], [Sort]
FROM cte
ORDER BY [Contents];
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e444975b959e54a30f3c2c5b9ebba362) (optimize types adjusting for their matching in CTE by yourself).

Comment: The values of  [content] are just examples in the table ，i can put any words ，like "hi",nice to meet you".......etc

Comment: @劉雨點 You have not specified the ordering for output recordset explicitly. But you MUST do it.

Comment: i don't know what is specified the ordering for output recordset explicitly mean??(Can you describe it briefly?

Comment: @劉雨點 You show the output which is identical to source data except the ordering. This means that you need to reorder your records (i.e. they must be in shown order in output). If not - you have asked not the same what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

U can try:

```
    WITH RECURSIVETABLE (ID, [PARENTID], [CONTENTS],[LEVELS],[SORT],[ORDER]) AS
(
    ------ START-------
  SELECT A.ID, A.[PARENTID], A.[CONTENTS],A.[FLOORS],A.[SORT], CONVERT(VARCHAR(250),RIGHT('00000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SORT)),5))
  FROM #TREETABLE A
 WHERE
  A.PARENTID  = 0 
   ------ END ---------
    UNION ALL
  SELECT B.ID, B.[PARENTID], B.[CONTENTS],B.[FLOORS],B.[SORT], CONVERT(VARCHAR(250),CONVERT(VARCHAR,A.[ORDER])+'.'+RIGHT('00000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY B.[FLOORS],B.SORT)),5)) 
  FROM #TREETABLE B
  JOIN RECURSIVETABLE A ON A.ID =B.PARENTID
    )
 SELECT * FROM RECURSIVETABLE ORDER BY [ORDER]
```